# Query element api (output) via plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-elementapi

Is there a way to fetch the content generated by the Element API via a plugin.

For example, if we have created an `ingredients/<slug:{slug}>.json` endpoint, can the data for a specific page (eg `ingredients/lemon.json`) be queried at the code level without having to fetch it via curl or similar?

Cheers,

Cole